# PDB debugger stability questions

Tags: debugging, anaconda, psycopg2, pdb, stability

I am using either pdb or ipdb for debugging my python code.  However whenever I am using set_trace() I can typically run a handful of lines of code to test but it eventually freezes while I am typing.  I kill the python process and have to re-run the entire process from the start - which usually kills about 5-10 minutes of data processing time to get back to where I was.

I am using an anaconda build with python 2.7.

The only anomaly I have is that I needed to run
`conda install -c conda-forge psycopg2=2.6.2` in order to be able to use psycopg2.  I have been ignoring it for the last two months but realize that it isn't an acceptable work flow.

Any thoughts to help resolve would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a little hard to help without a code example... can you produce a minimal example of your script that reproduces the error you have?

Comment: There is a lot of code involved I don't think that would necessarily help.  I watched the resource usage -- nothing was particularly constrained.  I am doing a lot of data processing but nothing greater than a 1 gb (have about 16 gb RAM).  Does it have a tipping point at which it fails from resource usage?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it.

I still don't know why this behavior is happening but if I press caps lock twice while it is frozen - it unlocks the set_trace.  Don't ask me why but it works.